# How can i change many property of a Map in immutable js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have this map

`Immutable.Map({ winChance : 49.99, rollOver : 49.99, payOut : 1.98, rollToggle : 1,})`

Is there any way to change this map at one time cause I want to return it in a function

I want something like this :

```
return state.set({'winChance':winChance,'payOut':payOut,'rollOver':rollOver})
```

can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, can you clarify what is your issue ?

Comment: you know if i want to change 4 property of this map i want to use .set 4 times 
i wanna to change it in once 
can you help me ?

Comment: If this is a React application, you can use `this.setState({winChance, payOut, rollOver});`.

Comment: you don't know even what is immutable JS then you  come here and give me negative 1 
what is wrong with you 
i ask a question about immutable JS 
i use flux for my react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the new values, you can [`.merge()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/merge) values in it.

```
const myMap = Immutable.Map({ winChance : 49.99, rollOver : 49.99, payOut : 1.98, rollToggle : 1,});
const myNewMap = myMap.merge(Immutable.Map({
  winChance : 22.22,
  // Other values
}));
```